# Как собрать динамический SQL с динамическими bind переменными?

Tags: sql, oracle

Когда проект был маленький и стал понемногу разрастаться количеством фильтров, было принято решение переписать процедуры по отбору данных на динамический `SQL`. Выглядело это вполне себе нормально

```
PROCEDURE getData(
  Filter1 IN VARCHAR2, 
  Filter2 IN VARCHAR2, 
  RES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
  tSQL: CLOB;
  BEGIN
    tSQL := 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 1 = 1';
    
    IF (Filter1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQL = TSQL || ' and product = ''' || Filter1 || ''' ';
    END IF;
    
    IF (Filter2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQL = TSQL || ' and subProduct = ''' || Filter2 || ''' ';
    END IF;
    
    OPEN res FOR tSQL;
    
  END;
```

Позже, проект рос и появилась потребность множественного выбора из одного поля. Создал тип **nested table**(вложенная таблица), переделал запрос. Так как данный тип нельзя указывать напрямую в запросе, приходится для каждого такого фильтра объявлять отдельную переменную.

```
create or replace type strings is table of varchar2(256);
-- -------------
PROCEDURE getData(
  Filter1 IN VARCHAR2, 
  Filter2 IN VARCHAR2, 
  Filter3 IN strings,
  RES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
  tSQL: CLOB;
  b1 strings;
  bindNum number := 0;
  BEGIN
    tSQL := 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 1 = 1 ';
    
    IF (Filter1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQL = TSQL || ' and product = ''' || Filter1 || ''' ';
    END IF;
    
    IF (Filter2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQL = TSQL || ' and subProduct = ''' || Filter2 || ''' ';
    END IF;
    
    IF (Filter3 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQl := tSQL || ' AND categories IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:b1)) ) ';
      b1 := Filter3;
      bindNum := bindNum + 1;
    END IF;
    
    IF (bindNum = 1) then
      OPEN res FOR tSQL USING b1;
    ELSE
      OPEN res FOR tSQL;
    END IF;
    
  END;
```

Далее мне необходимо вести "учет" количества задействованных переменных, что бы правильно вызывать `SQL` запрос. Так количество объявленных **bind** переменных должно строго равняться количеству передаваемых переменных, то это вылилось вот в такую, не очень красивую конструкцию

```
IF (bindIter = 0) THEN
  OPEN res FOR tsql;
ELSIF (bindIter =1) THEN
  OPEN res FOR tsql USING b1;
ELSIF (bindIter =2) THEN
  OPEN res FOR tsql USING b1, b2;
... END etc
ELSE
  OPEN res FOR tsql USING b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10;
END IF;
```

При этом, знаю, что у заказчика потребности будут расти и растягивать эту портянку будет сущим адом...

Попробовал переехать на пакет **DBMS_SQL**, все показалось красивым, НО... Там нельзя биндить переменные до того, как открыт курсор и передан `SQL` запрос.

```
DECLARE
  cur NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_sql.open_cursor(cur); -- Открыть курсор
  dbms_sql.parse(cur, 'select :x from dual', dbms_sql.native); -- Вставить запрос
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(cur, ':x', '1'); -- Определять переменные
END;
```

Конечно, выглядеть это будет красивее, но я не уйду от безумного количества переменных и последующих проверок(сначала в IF проверяем, а есть ли данные для вписывания условия в WHERE, а потом в IF проверять, а надо ли биндить ту или иную переменную).

Смотрел в сторону **JSON**, но как мне кажется, это мою проблему не решит.

Oracle 19c, сервер реализован на nodeJS.

Как можно формировать динамический `SQL` более правильно, уходя от множественного определения переменных? Возможно есть другие способы сделать это?

Comment: Это что то вроде изобретения ОРМ? или ближе к именованым параметрам?

Comment: Это ближе к именованным параметрам. Процедура на вход принимает(сейчас) около 20 параметров. Из них заполнено может быть 0, а может... Сейчас код уже выглядит кошмарно, особенно сборка бинд, их подсчет и потом выбор open for с нужным количеством(а еще надо не ошибиться порядком следования, если что то середину заплывает). Хотелось что то вроде того - данные пришли, забиндил сразу, а потом вызвал.

Comment: Возможно вот это можно адаптировать до нормального уровня, но я не уверен, http://forum.codenet.ru/q56626/ , можно передавать элементы "ключ" => "значение" и перебирая в цикле добавлять части запроса

Comment: Для Sql Server я всегда рекомендую [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) (и другие статьи автора). Элегантный способ в разделе [4.2 The Basic Technique](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#BasicStaticSQL): `WHERE (column1 = @param1 OR @param1 IS NULL) AND (column2 = @param2 OR @param2 IS NULL)` и т. д. Насколько я знаю, в Oracle это тоже работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы собираете основной запрос `tSQL` динамически, то что мешает собрать скрипт открытия курсора `OPEN res FOR tsql USING b1, b2, ...` тоже динамически?

Ничего не мешает:

```
create type numbers as table of number;
create type named_list_of_numbers as object ( name varchar2(100), list numbers );
create type named_lists_of_numbers as table of named_list_of_numbers;
    
declare
    c sys_refcursor;
    a number;
    a2 number;
    a3 number;
    
    procedure getData(
        p_lists named_lists_of_numbers, 
        o_cur out sys_refcursor
    ) is
        v_sql clob;
        v_open_sql varchar2(1000);
    begin      
        v_sql := '
            select 
                x, square, cube 
            from 
                (
                    select 
                        level x, 
                        level*level square, 
                        level*level*level cube 
                    from dual 
                    connect by level < 10
                ) 
            where 0=1';
        v_open_sql := '
            declare 
                args named_lists_of_numbers := :all_args; 
            begin 
                open :cur for :sql using ';
        for j in 1 .. p_lists.count loop  
            v_sql := v_sql || '
                or ' || p_lists(j).name || ' in (select column_value from table(:arr' || j || '))' ;
            v_open_sql := v_open_sql || case when j > 1 then ', ' end || 'args(' || j || ').list' ;
        end loop; 
        v_open_sql := v_open_sql || ';
            end;' ;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_open_sql);
        execute immediate v_open_sql using p_lists, o_cur, v_sql;
    end;    
    
begin
    getData( 
        named_lists_of_numbers(
            named_list_of_numbers('x', numbers(2, 3)),
            named_list_of_numbers('square', numbers(25)),
            named_list_of_numbers('cube', numbers(343, 512))
        ), 
        c
    );
    loop
        fetch c into a, a2, a3;
        exit when c%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(a||chr(9)||a2||chr(9)||a3);
    end loop;
    close c;    
end;
```